Why countQuery is needed in Spring Boot 2.7.8. Is there any other way to do pagination?
I am building a project using Spring Boot 2.7.8. On a page, I need to change the pagination features, but I am writing two methods for pageable and one method is fetching actual details (using pagination) which returns Page object and another one is total count. I have read some articles using only one method for both data and total count, but Spring Boot 2.7.8 does not seem to support that.
@Query(value =  "select * from product_master",nativeQuery = true)
List<productMaster> findallscroll(Pageable pageable);
         
@Query(value =  "select count(*) from product_master",nativeQuery = true)
int findallscrollcount();

or
@Query(value = " select  * FROM product_master pm \n" + 
            "WHERE pm.product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_soc_details soc where soc.product_soc_id= :copysocid or soc.product_soc_id= :socid) and pm.status!=2 ",
            countQuery = " select  * FROM product_master pm \n" + 
                    "WHERE pm.product_id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM product_soc_details soc where soc.product_soc_id= :copysocid or soc.product_soc_id= :socid) and pm.status!=2 ", nativeQuery = true)
    Page<productMaster> findProductsByFilterinProductSocAllCopy(int copysocid,int socid,Pageable pageable);

Is there any way to do this without the extra method or countQuery?

Spring Boot 2.7.8 does support pageable the problem is how you are using it.
To fix it remove nativeQuery = true from first query and it will work as expected.
When using nativeQuery = true, you have to tell explicitly to spring-data-jpa that you are expecting a pageable response and this is why you have to pass also countQuery parameter.
More information about how it works you will be able to find out if you open java docs of the annotation @Query
